# How does BINs vulnerabilities work?

Tags: account-security, data-validation

Many companies have some BINs where you can enter a fake credit card and you get a premium account (the Credit card is based on a BIN that just trick or bypass the plateform),

I want to know how this works ?

For example : bin spotify/netflix etc.. 5273XXXXXXXX

How people can discover these bins ? And how/why they work ?

Comment: What does BIN mean? I'm not familiar with that acronym.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I guess it means Bank Identification Number.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the first two octets of the card number (although in a lot of cases, only the first six numbers are used) are reserved as an IIN ([Issuer Identification Number](https://www.ansi.org/other_services/registration_programs/iin)). These are what you to refer to as BIN numbers, however the term "BIN" (Bank Identification Number) is generally not used anymore. These IINs are used to identify which card processing organisation the processing of the card should be directed towards.

Card Numbers have an algorithmic validation check built in to make sure they are valid before sending anything off to a server. This algorithmic validation check follows the [modulus 10 algorithm (aka the Luhn Algorithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). This is how PayPal, WorldPay and all the other companies that process card details are able to instantly tell you that your card was entered incorrectly, without sending your details over the internet constantly.

The algorithm follows the following simple steps:

1. Double every second digit (so, if you have 1 **2** 3 **4**, you'd double 2 & 4)
2. If your double is ten or greater, then add the individual digits together (let's say you doubled 8, you'd get 16 - you would add 1 and 6 together to get 7)
3. Add all of these digits you've performed operations on together. So, in our first case, we'd add (2 x 2) and (4 x 2) together, producing ten. If the number ends with a zero (you calculate this by performing [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) 10 on the number, and comparing to zero) then the card number is valid.

Further to this, all major card providers have their own assigned IINs or ranges of IINs. This is why when you're typing, many websites will instantly identify Visa (beginning with 4) or Mastercard (beginning with 51 through 55).

The reason some websites will allow you to enter in fake credit cards is because it's difficult to establish if the card is active and genuine. The primary way to do this is charging a small amount to the card, which is often not worth the trouble. The websites won't be checking if that card is active, they'll be checking if it is a card meeting the technical standards. Hence, until they try and bill it, they will have no idea if the card is genuinely active.

Some companies need more verification than this, however. PayPal for example charges you with a unique code reference that you must tell them to ensure that, not only is the card active, but it's also a card you control. This is a measure to prevent card fraud.